# Font size change when I change the font?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am currently using `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}`, so 12pt size. However, I decided to change the font by using

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

and suddenly the font got bigger (not sure what size though, I will attach pictures for comparison purposes. Same resolution, same chapter size, however the text in the body is obviously bigger). So my question is, how can I avoid that?

[[image]]
[[image]]

Comment: Which font family were you using before switching to the Helvetica clone?

Comment: The default one in overleaf?  I havent picked one out specifically, everything I used was `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}`

Comment: helvetica has a much bigger x-height than computer modern so lowercase is larger if you keep uppercase the same but you can use `\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}` or whatever

Comment: the declared font sizes are the same but a font size is just a label, not a length that can be measured both are 12pt fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Computer Modern` -- the default (serif) font for all TeX systems I'm familiar with -- and `Helvetica` differ strongly across several categories. Among these are x-heights, ascender heights, stroke thickness, and compactness/condensedness.

I take it from your posting that you want to equate the x-heights of the two fonts. To do so, load the `helvet` package with the option `scaled=0.835`. (I arrived at the value 0.835 by casual empiricism.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}

% scaled=0.835 to equate x-heights of Computer Modern and Helvetica
% scaled=0.935 to equate ascender heights of Computer Modern and Helvetica
\usepackage[scaled=0.835]{helvet} 
%%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
xxx\textsf{xxx}xxx

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \textsf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Prepare the following input file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\cmheight}
\newlength{\helvheight}

\settoheight\cmheight{x}
\settoheight\helvheight{\sffamily x}

\fpeval{round(\cmheight/\helvheight,5)}

\settoheight\cmheight{A}
\settoheight\helvheight{\sffamily A}

\fpeval{round(\cmheight/\helvheight,5)}

\end{document}
```

You may need `\usepackage{xfp}` if you aren't running the most recent LaTeX release.

Upon running LaTeX you'll get

0.8272
0.9458

These are the scale factors for the two cases you may want: in the first case the x-height of Helvetica will be the same as Computer Modern; in the second case the height of capital letters will be the same.

Indeed, in Helvetica the ratio between x-height and capital letter height is different than in Computer Modern.

Now let's make a couple of experiments.

#### First experiment: same x-height

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.8272]{helvet}

\begin{document}

Abcdef\textsf{Abcdef}

x\textsf{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Second experiment: same capital letter height

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.9458]{helvet}

\begin{document}

Abcdef\textsf{Abcdef}

x\textsf{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Conclusion

If you want all the document in Helvetica, decide whatever scaling you seem fit, between the two given bounds.

I'd probably go with 0.94